# Using jScrollPane to scroll to a certain position

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to scroll to a certain position when clicking play on HTML5 video player.

I have the video scrolling to the far left of the div when play is selected, but I need it to be 165px from the far left of the div.

Can anyone help please?

```
jQuery('video').bind(
'play',
function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

jScrollPaneAPI.scrollToElement($(this).parent(), true, true);
}
);

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.scroll-to-click').trigger('click');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollToX()` or `scrollToY()` functions